Importing an image into google cloud - ends up with no network
I have an appliance from a vendor that I'm trying to import into google cloud.
I can not import it with guest environment (it fails).
Once imported I can spin up a vm but I do not have root access to the vm.
The issue I'm seeing is that the machine comes up with no ethernet, which I can't change because I don't have root :/
I'm pretty sure this is the issue;
@localhost:/etc$ ip l show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:aa:aa:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:f1:00:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

/etc/netplan$ cat /etc/netplan/config.yaml 

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens4:
      dhcp4: true

The image is looking for ens4 but the os thinks the devices are called "eth0" and "eth1".
Question is, is there a way to fix this in the import or do I need to go to the vendor to try get a root shell?
Tried multiple ways of importing the image

Can you connect via the serial port? What do you mean by I don't have root?
